# Is there a difference between a^2 and a^2L?

Tags: r

Is there a difference between `a^2` and `a^2L` in **R**?

Speed difference?

Precision?

So far I see none, just wondering if ^2 is implemented as log/exp pair, but ^2L as a multiplication. What about if `a` is not just a vector?

UPDATE

No, it is NOT a duplicate, I know about difference between `2` and `2L`. Question is, does this difference play a role for the power operator?

Comment: Regarding if there is a difference, you could have done benchmarking by yourself ...

Comment: Maybe.  [mlutils.c](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/b156e3a711967f58131e23c1b1dc1ea90e2f0c43/src/nmath/mlutils.c) has both `R_pow` and `R_pow_di` , but I haven't checked farther upstream to see if `R_pow_di` is used by the parser.

Comment: FWIW regarding speed, using `2` is _very slightly_ faster than using `2L`, but the difference is imho negligible (mean diff 10 milliseconds on my machine, on a vector of length 1e7)

Comment: I benchmarked it with `microbenchmark` a bunch of times and they kept flipping for which was slower, so I assume they're pretty equal. Using `print((1/3)^2, digits = 22)`, they seem to have the same floating point error, too. According to `?\`^\``, `^` is implemented with C's `pow` for doubles; it doesn't say for integers.

Comment: @Heroka my machine shows the opposite...

Comment: @MichaelChirico I think the conclusion here is "there is no difference in speed"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R uses an integer exponent version [`R_pow_di`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/a2e7ab3faa86767c4a45ed4dac3b4b9f9bc71eca/src/main/arithmetic.c#L244) internally, but the [`^` operator](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/87acb9654142e78f696aa5210ae33554e2b6f8ce/src/main/eval.c#L5689) only calls [`R_pow`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/a2e7ab3faa86767c4a45ed4dac3b4b9f9bc71eca/src/main/arithmetic.c#L200). That being said, `R_pow` *does* special case `x^2` as `x*x`. Therefore, the precision is identical, but the `2L` version ought to be slightly slower due to long->double coercion at the C level. This is demonstrated in the following benchmark.

```
lngs<-rep(2L,1e6)
dbls<-rep(2.0,1e6)
n<-sample(100,1e6,replace=TRUE)
x<-rnorm(1e6)
microbenchmark(x^lngs,x^dbls,n^lngs,n^dbls)
# Unit: milliseconds
#    expr       min        lq      mean    median       uq      max neval cld
#  x^lngs  8.489547  9.804030 12.543227 11.719721 13.98702 19.92170   100  b 
#  x^dbls  5.622067  6.724312  9.432223  7.949713 10.89252 59.15342   100 a  
#  n^lngs 10.590587 13.857297 14.920559 14.200080 16.65519 19.55346   100   c
#  n^dbls  8.331087  9.699143 12.414267 11.403211 14.20562 19.66389   100  b
```

This is nothing to lose sleep over.

Links go to the source mirror. Note that `R_ADD`, `R_SUB`, `R_MUL` and `R_DIV` are defined as C macros to take advantage of type overloading, but [`R_POW`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/a2e7ab3faa86767c4a45ed4dac3b4b9f9bc71eca/src/main/arithmetic.h#L35) is defined to inline the `x^2 = x*x` special case then calls `R_pow` (lower case). The checking for that special case again in `R_pow` would be duplicative except that `R_pow` is called internally other places.

Comment: Does the ^ operator behave differently on scalars vs. vectors? I just tried to ask this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/72822092

Answer (score 6):

My conclusion is that it is *ever-so-slightly* faster *if and only if* the base is an integer as well, *on scalars*.

My benchmark:

```
library(microbenchmark)
set.seed(1230)
num <- rnorm(1L)
int <- sample(100L, 1L)
microbenchmark(times = 100000L,
               num^2L,
               num^2,
               int^2L,
               int^2)
```

And timings on my machine:

```
# Unit: nanoseconds
#    expr min  lq     mean median  uq      max neval
#  num^2L  99 115 161.8495    121 166    11047 1e+05
#   num^2  97 113 196.8615    119 165  3645369 1e+05
#  int^2L  89 107 140.3745    111 120     3319 1e+05
#   int^2  98 115 525.1727    120 166 34776551 1e+05
```

If base or exponent is a numeric, the median time is basically identical (though maybe `num ^ num` has a fat upper tail?).

## The Penalty of Size

Despite the advantage of `integer ^ integer` on scalars, it appears (as explicated by @A.Webb in his own answer) that, for vectors of any reasonable size, `numeric ^ numeric` is faster, and, for vectors of a reasonably common range of medium sizes, it's much faster.

Results from 500 benchmarks:

```
set.seed(1230)
ns <- as.integer(10^(seq(0, 6, length.out = 500L)))
mbs <- sapply(ns, function(n){
  num = rnorm(n); int = as.integer(num)
  summary(microbenchmark(times = 2000L, num ^ 2L, num ^ 2, int ^ 2L, int ^ 2), 
          unit = "relative")$median
})
```

[image: 5k]

This first plot gets the gist of things. `n` means `numeric` and `i` means `integer`.

Eventually, the fixed cost of the size of the vector does eat away at the advantage:

[image: 1e6]

Only at negligible lengths is `i ^ i` fastest:

[image: 50]

---

The gist of plotting is this:

```
matplot(ns[ns < 5000], t(mbs[ , ns < 5000]),
        type = "l", lty = 1L, lwd = 3L,
        xlab = "length", ylab = "Relative Time",
        main = "Through Length 5000",
        col = c("black", "red", "green", "blue"))
legend("topleft", c("n ^ i", "n ^ n", "i ^ i", "i ^ n"),
       col = c("black", "red", "green", "blue"),
       lty = 1L, lwd = 3L)
```