# Reduce computation time of simple function

Tags: r

I have a simple function, which is called hundreds of times. Is there any way to improve the speed of its computation?

```
# the input variable (y) is a scalar
my_function <- function(y){
 ret_value <- 0.5*((max(0,y)**2)-(3*max(0,y-1)**2)+(3*max(0,y-2)**2)-(max(0,y-3)**2))
 return(ret_value)
}
```

I already tried with an `if`& `else if` statement, which resulted in a slightly longer computation time.

I also read a lot about the `rcpp`package, but it is my understanding that a C++ implementation is mostly helpful for more complicated structures such as recursions and multiple loops. Not sure if there would be any improvement for such a simple function as mine.

EDIT: The parent function is as follows and as such, a vectorization would probably be the best idea. What's the best / fastest way to do so?

```
val1 <- 0.9
val2 <- 0.7
F_val <- 1
loop_seq <- c(1, 2, 3)
for(i in loop_seq){
 for(j in loop_seq){
  F_val <- F_val + my_function(val1-i)*my_function(val2-j)
 }
}
```

My current solution is the following, but I didn't really get any speed improvement:

```
ret_value <- 0.5*apply(matrix(pmax(0,rep(y_vec,each=4)+c(0,-1,-2,-3))^2*c(1,-3,3,-1), ncol=length(y_vec)),2,sum)
```

Comment: "which is called hundreds of times" and "the input variable (y) is a scalar" -- if you can pass a vector, naturally that will be faster; see `?pmax`. However, calling this function hundreds of times with scalar input should be pretty much instant, right? `system.time(replicate(1e5, my_function(1)))` is under a second on my computer.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, it is not possible to pass a vector in my overall problem setting. Also, the number of calls is probably much higher as it is part of a large optimization problem and profiling gave me the following self times: my_funtion (17.54), my_function_derivative (14.62) and max (10.62). So it adds up quite a bit.

Comment: There likely needs to be more context here. Often times *"not possible to pass a vector"* is a misunderstanding of how R works, not a limitation of the language. I'm not saying we know your stuff better, but it's a common-enough mistake that it's generally safe for us to lean in that direction. Otherwise, I cannot see any reasonable way to speed this up. (Vectorizing this with just `pmax` in place of `max` reduced the run-time on my machine by two orders of magnitude. Perhaps your question should be *"how can I change <the parent process> to support vectorizing?"*.)

Comment: Thanks r2evans, I checked it again and it should indeed be possible. I updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `**2` is where the time is spend. Replaced it with multiplication

```
mff <- function(y) {
    a <- if (y < 0.0) 0.0 else y
    b <- if (y < 1.0) 0.0 else y-1.0
    c <- if (y < 2.0) 0.0 else y-2.0
    d <- if (y < 3.0) 0.0 else y-3.0
    0.5*(a*a - 3.0*b*b + 3.0*c*c - d*d)
}
```

On my machine your original function

```
> system.time(replicate(1e6, mf(0.7)))
   user  system elapsed 
   2.88    0.00    2.88
```

Mine

```
> system.time(replicate(1e6, mff(0.7)))
   user  system elapsed 
   1.48    0.03    1.52
```

UPDATE

It is also easy to vectorize this function with `ifelse()`

```
vecmff <- function(y) {
    a <- ifelse(y < 0.0, 0.0, y)
    b <- ifelse(y < 1.0, 0.0, y-1.0)
    c <- ifelse(y < 2.0, 0.0, y-2.0)
    d <- ifelse(y < 3.0, 0.0, y-3.0)
    0.5*(a*a - 3.0*b*b + 3.0*c*c - d*d)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great. How did you find out? I was feeling like searching for the needle in a haystack ...

Comment: @tstudio I had issues with power function in **R** before (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35346858/is-there-a-difference-between-a2-and-a2l), so I know it is not a cheap thing. Also, take a look at profiling **R**: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Profiling.html. And take a look at update

Comment: @tstudio Forgot to mention one thing, which might help you with **R** performance in general - I'm running Microsoft **R** open (artist, formerly known as Revolution **R**), which is optimized for performance and linked against Intel MKL library. For my codes (which are more of scientific computing in nature) it is quite faster than standard **R** distribution. Link: https://mran.microsoft.com/open