# `x^(1/3)` behaves differently for negative scalar `x` and vector `x` with negative values

Tags: r, numeric, exponent

R seems pretty comfortable with computing the odd root of a negative number

```
-0.2^(1/3) # returns a good number 
# [1] -0.5848035
```

but something weird happens if you raise a vector to the 1/3.

```
c(-0.2, 1)^(1/3) # returns an NA for the first element
# [1] NaN   1
```

I'm interested in an answer that explains what is happening *differently* to the vector than to the negative value when provided as a numeric scalar.

I'm not looking for a workaround e.g. `function(x){sign(x)*(abs(x))^(1/3)}`. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35348833/8400969) seems to point in a good direction... how does the "^" operator think differently about vectors and scalars?

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-are-powers-of-negative-numbers-wrong_003f

Comment: @BenBolker, Thanks, this is pretty clear in the R documentation. Might be good to add the example @ZheyuanLi added `(-0.2)^(1/3)` returns `NA`.

Comment: I'm sort of amazed that I hadn't directly run into this problem until now (or not realized it)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm not looking for a workaround e.g. `function(x) {sign(x) * (abs(x)) ^ (1/3)}`.

> I'm interested in an answer that explains what is happening differently to the vector than to the negative value when provided as a numeric scalar.

> how does the `^` operator think differently about vectors and scalars?

You seem to believe that `c(-0.2, 1)^(1/3)` translates to `c(-0.2^(1/3), 1^(1/3))`. This is incorrect. Operator `^` is actually a function, that is, `(a) ^ (b)` is as same as `"^"(a, b)`. Therefore, the correct interpretation goes as follows:

```
   c(-0.2, 1)^(1/3)
=> "^"(c(-0.2, 1), 1/3)
=> c( "^"(-0.2, 1/3), "^"(1, 1/3) )
=> c( (-0.2)^(1/3), (1)^(1/3) )
=> c( NaN, 1 )
```

Now, why doesn't `-0.2^(1/3)` give `NaN`? Because `^` has higher operation precedence than `+`, `-`, `*` and `/`. So as it is written, it really implies `-(0.2^(1/3))` instead of `(-0.2)^(1/3)`.

The lesson is that, to avoid buggy code, write your code as `(a) ^ (b)` instead of just `a ^ b`.

---

**Additional Remark:**

I often compare `^` and `:` when teaching **R** to my students, because they have different behaviors. But they all show the importance of protecting operands with brackets.

```
(-1):2
#[1] -1  0  1  2

-1:2
#[1] -1  0  1  2

-(1:2)
#[1] -1 -2
```

```
2*3:10
#[1]  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20

(2*3):10
#[1]  6  7  8  9 10

2*(3:10)
#[1]  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20
```

See `?Syntax` for details of operator precedence.