# Weird exponent behavior in R 4.1.2?

Tags: r

I'm finding a very weird issue that I can't figure out if it is a Bug or a Feature:

```r
c(-1333.47,-1333.47)^0.41
[1] NaN NaN
```

When the behavior should be:

```r
c(-1333.47^0.41,-1333.47^0.41)
[1] -19.10923 -19.10923
```

Am I missing something here? Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: Um, I guess the first is correct, you cannot take the root of a negative number. You need to change it to an imaginary number to get the root. The second part takes the root first, then multiply with `-1`.

Comment: I just learned about this too, and it's not new to a specific R version, and I guess it's a "feature", totally about order of operations. Here was my version of this same question a few days ago, also marked as a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72822092/8400969

Comment: What do you mean by how the behaviour _should be_ ? Mathematically, you can't raise a negative number to a fractional power. The result you are getting in the second example is because of the `^` having higher operator precedence than the `-`, so it is interpreted as `-(1333.47^0.41)`

Comment: @ZheyuanLi, feel free to upvote it; I felt comfortable with the answer provided and the answer linked as a duplicate as both got to the heart of the matter.

Comment: Thank you guys...I see it now...total brain-fart on my behalf

Comment: @Allan Cameron. This should be an answer. Many thanks! Also the question by Michael that is linked is worth to read!